# How to remove only files and ignore subfolders on GIT

Tags: git, github

I want to be able to remove all the files in my local folder and in github, but I have a sub folder that I don't want to touch.

How do I delete all the files while ignoring the sub folder?

Comment: Do you want to execute it on your local machine and commit the changes to git?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commit and push the results of

```
git rm -r \*
git read-tree -u --prefix=path/to/it/ @:path/to/it
```

If you want to preserve your indexed state, insert a `` x=`git write-tree` `` above and sub in `$x` for the `@`.

Since that's going to kill your `.gitignore`s you can make an untracked one containing

```
!*
path/to/it/
```

and then `git clean -df` will wipe all the untracked files except those in that path.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running *nix :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs git rm
```

inside the folder.

To avoid removing hidden files (e.g. `.gitignore`) :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v '/\.' | xargs git rm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your .git & sub-folder outside the repo.

```
$ cp .git ~/TEST
$ cp sub-folder-name ~/TEST
```

Then delete all the files and also folders

```
$ rm -rf *
```

Copy the .git and sub-folder in your repo

```
$ cp ~/TEST/.git .
$ cp ~/TEST/sub-folder-name .
```

Then push to github

```
$ git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be:

```
git rm *.{fileending1,fileending2,...}
```

or:

```
git rm yourfirstfile yoursecondfile ...
```